# Where can I find a C program to implement CBC (Cipher block chaining) decryption?

Tags: encryption

I want a program which takes an encrypted string and it should be decrypted by the program using CBC algorithm. Is there any website which has such programs on encryption and decryption?

Comment: iirc cbc is an add-on to block-ciphers, not a cipher itself

Comment: maybe the target is an embedded system. openssl is somewhat too huge for that

Answer (score 2):

CBC is a block cipher chaining method, and can be applied to any block cipher, such as DES, AES, IDEA, etc.

A very comprehensive crypto library written in portable C is [libtomcrypt](http://libtom.org/?page=features&whatfile=crypt). Perhaps you can use it.